# Rails has_many :through --> How do you set up an association to pull from multiple join models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I'd like to set up multiple has_many :through relationships in parallel. Here are my 2 standard and 2 join models:

**User.rb**

```
has_many :ownerships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :devices, through: :ownerships

has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :devices, through: :bookings
```

**Ownership.rb**

```
belongs_to :user, touch: true, counter_cache: :devices_count
belongs_to :device, touch: true
```

**Booking.rb**

```
belongs_to :user, touch: true, counter_cache: :bookings_count 
belongs_to :device, touch: true, counter_cache: :bookings_count
```

**Device.rb**

```
has_many :ownerships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :ownerships

has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :bookings
```

This current setup is NOT working as expected, there seems to be crosstalk between the join models. I want the join models to be independent and in parallel (i.e. Users can have relationships - Ownerships - with devices independently of being able to book them). I am not looking for a nested has_many :through relation here.

When I change the User Ownerships of a Device that seems to alter the number of Bookings and vice versa... any ideas on how should I be setting this up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I think the first error you've got is you're calling two associations by the same name (`users` / `devices`)

To help any further respondents, the real question is --> **`how do you set up an association to pull from multiple join models?`**

---

**Quick Fix**

Rails associations are named primarily by their class, but because of conflicts, you should refrain from setting them twice. This is why you're seeing the current issue. A simple resolution will be to call the associations by different names:

```
User.rb
has_many :ownerships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :owner_devices, through: :ownerships, class_name: "Device", foreign_key: "ownership_id"

has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :booking_devices, through: :ownerships, class_name: "Device", foreign_key: "booking_id"
```

I am still looking for information on how you could set an association to use two models

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think it is on the right track. Are you sure the foreign_keys are correct as listed? Shouldn't they be ownership_id and booking_id, respectively?

Comment: No problem - Nope I'm not sure if they're right :) I will have a look!

Comment: This is just a quick fix; as for providing multiple sets of data for one association -- I'll need to learn about this

Comment: Check the answer I posted, will try that first and play around with the it. But I think that's the gist of it, definitely needed the aliases and references to class_name. Now its just a matter of figuring out the correct foreign_ids.

Comment: Let me know if it works. If you get errors / problems, let me know & we can work through it. One of the problems of answering "in depth" questions on SO is that I'd have to recreate your environment to gauge responses etc; something I'd prefer to let the asker to do, as its their setup which we're working to fix!

Answer (score 1):

This appears be a working solution following Rich Peck's suggestions:

**User.rb**

```
has_many :ownerships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :device_ownerships, through: :ownerships, class_name: "Device", foreign_key: "device_id", source: :device

has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :device_bookings, through: :bookings, class_name: "Device", foreign_key: "device_id", source: :device
```

**Booking.rb** (Join model)

```
belongs_to :user, touch: true, counter_cache: :bookings_count 
belongs_to :device, touch: true, counter_cache: :bookings_count
```

**Ownership.rb** (Join model)

```
belongs_to :user, touch: true, counter_cache: :devices_count
belongs_to :device, touch: true, counter_cache: :users_count
```

**Device.rb**

```
has_many :ownerships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :user_ownerships, through: :ownerships, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id", source: :user

has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :user_bookings, through: :bookings, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id", source: :user
```

To be honest, I'm a bit confused over why the foreign_key's need(?) to be set up as they are, so I'll have to do a bit more reading about it. Otherwise it appears to be functional, I don't see crosstalk between these join models anymore.

Comment: Good work - the `foriegn_key` is basically a variable to define the right column name if you're using non-conventional associations. It's best to think of the associations as methods, which have automated options derived from the name. If you're using a non-standard name, your arguments need to be amended to sui t:)

Comment: BTW you might want to upvote my answer if it helped ;)